Can Windows Server Backup automatically change the configuration?
So I have a full copy scheduled every day (I know it is not optimal) that is destined for an external drive with a capacity of 1TB. Let's say that the copies, being complete of the entire disk, weigh approximately 600GB, which means that only one copy fits on the disk. My question is whether Windows Backup can automatically change the configuration of the copies and go from making a complete copy of the C: partition to making incremental copies due to lack of space, since as far as I know the copies were being overwritten on top of the first but two days ago these became incremental and I have not changed the configuration at any time

but two days ago these became incremental and I have not changed the configuration at any time - How did you determine that?

use a professional proper software like veeam if you only backup with WBS it will be a improvement

@joeqwerty I notified because the last two backups were incremental and they are scheduled to be daily

@djdomi I use WBS just as a secondary backup I have another backup solution on cloud which is the primary backup

No. The configuration will not change if the storage becomes less. Changing from full backup to incremental backup requires manual intervention only
